# Verifying existence of a root level element with jq

Tags: json, bash, jq

Given a JSON structure such as below, I want to test for the existence of the `sys/` top-level key.

```
{                                                                                                                                                             
  "abc/": {                                                                                                                                             
    "uuid": "fd"
   },
 "sys/": {                                                                                                                                                   
    "uuid": "id2"
  }
}
```

I have tried various constructs such as `jq "sys/"` or `jq "sys/.uuid"` but I get compile errors and/or errors such as "jq: error: sys/0 is not defined at , line 1:"

Note that it is important that the result code (`$?`) from `jq` returns correctly to reflect actual result (becuse this is being used in a config management test).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need to use the `has` attribute which returns a boolean value depending on the presence of the key mentioned

```
jq 'has("sys/")'
```

Note that you can customize `jq` to return a bool string or even `null`, but none of them can't be directly used in a shell conditional which only uses exit codes `0` or `1`.

If you want the result of the `jq` to be used in a shell conditional statement, you can make it return a exit code. There is an option which supports this. From the documentation

> `-e / --exit-status:`
>
> Sets the exit status of `jq` to `0` if the last output values was neither `false` nor `null`, `1` if the last output value was either `false` or `null`, or `4` if no valid result was ever produced.

So using this on your given JSON

```
jq -e 'has("sys/")' json > /dev/null
echo $?
0
```

but for a non-existent key `sys1`, it emits

```
jq -e 'has("sys1/")' json > /dev/null
echo $?
1
```

Note that the `> /dev/null` suppress the stdout thrown out on applying the filter, which is the boolean string value. If your `jq` version does not support the option or if you are looking for an alternate way to do this, you can directly match the string returned from the `has()` filter instead of evaluating the exit code i.e.

```
if [ $(jq 'has("sys/")' json) = "true" ]; then
    printf '%s\n' 'key present'
fi
```

Comment: Both those answers look great. My only problem is the return code from `jq` is true (0) on both. e.g. `jq 'has("nonexistent/")'` gives `$? = 0`

Comment: @LittleCode: It wasn't there in the OP, could you add a note that you want to use that in a conditional

Comment: Done.  I would have assumed something like a `has()` would reflect true/false in the return code anyway.

Answer (score -3):

Adding to previous answer, this is the way to do this in Python 3, in case someone is not able to install *jq* :

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3

import json

obj=json.loads("""{                                               
  "abc/": {                                                              
    "uuid": "fd"
   },
 "sys/": {                                                                
    "uuid": "id2"
  }
}""")

if 'sys/' in obj:
    exit(0)
else :
    exit(1)
```

Comment: You don't need to add answers for arbitrarily chosen alternatives to what the question actually asked for.

Comment: @chepner - that attitude IMHO diminishes the value of the SO, because SO exist not only for people to ask questions, but for the entire range, which include those who might be interested or even after the alternative solutions.

Comment: Actually, SO is *precisely* for answers to well-defined, *focused* questions. The OP did not ask for a Python solution; they did not ask for a Perl, Ruby, C, Haskell, R, Prolog, or Scheme solution. They asked for a `jq` solution. If you think answering the question for Python is doing, you can post your *own* self-answered question. But don't arbitrarily expand the scope of an existing question.

Comment: @chepner: `SO is precisely for answers to well-defined, focused questions` - citation needed. For the best suited answer, the SO (well, SE to be precise) provides a voting system. Here's a counter-argument for the alternative solutions: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300254/can-an-alternative-solution-be-an-answer

Comment: If you don't see a problem with allowing every question to treated as an invitation for solutions in any language imaginable, there's nothing more for me to say here.

Comment: @Dmitry you are a bit twisting the words of your own link. Alternative solutions doesn't mean different language. It means for example that for a question "how can I loop a list's indexes to find the largest value", you might suggest an answer iterating the list's elements instead of indexes

Comment: @Tomerikoo I agree with Dimitry's perspective. Answers should contribute to share knowledge WHILE reaching to a solution for OPs problem. In this specific case, its not uncommon to lack *jq* and also being unable to install it due to permission on the server. So finding another tool that mostly comes with any flavor of Linux and gets the job done I don't think affects the content negatively. My answer SHOULD NOT be highlighted as the correct one as its not what OP asked, but should be regarded as a small contribution that might be useful for some people who might bump into this in the future.

Comment: FYI I agree with @chepner. I asked specifically about jq and bash. If I wanted python I would have asked for it.  Furthermore, I don't even know how to program in python, so I never use it as a language anyway.